# URL rewrite rules not working using .htaccess on cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I was using cakephp 1.2 and recently i updated cake version and migrated to 2.4.

Before we were using many .htaccess rules for applications . We write them in /webroot/.htaccess file . But after the migration to 2.4 , any rules are not working .

E.G

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /news/$
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/news/ [QSA,L]

But this rules not working on cake 2.4. Can Anybody help me to solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to not use the `mod_rewrite` rules but to use the [`Router`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router) class instead.

If you edit the file `app/config/routes.php` and add a route like this (Assuming you want to call `PagesController::display('news')`):

```
Router::connect('/news/*', array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'display', 
    'news'
));
```

You should get the same result.

Comment: but isn't it possible to rewrite urls using .htaccess on cakephp 2.4?

Comment: It's not something I've tried. I've always stuck with using the Router class. Does [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess) help you at all?

Comment: We have some critical issues e.g static caching and some difficult url rewriting which we did using .htaccess. It will be better if we get any help how we can use .htaccess on cake2.4 as it was running on cake 1.3

Comment: Ok, well I don't think I'd be able to help with that. Sorry.